# I cant get code to detect the beginning of a link (www or https)

Tags: javascript, variables, discord

currently trying to get my code to notice the beginning of a message if its "www" or "https" and then checking if they're associated with either reddit or youtube, I've tried multiple different posts (there arent very many on the discord API for javascript) so Im kinda stumpted at this point

```
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
var protect = false;
const forbidenWords = ['reddit', 'youtube']
const Message = ''
bot.login(botconfig.token);


let prefix = "!";
bot.on("message", (message) => {



  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "protect")) {
    message.channel.send("PROTECT THE KING!!!!");
    protect = true;
    console.log('protecc is true')

  } else

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "stop")) {
    message.channel.send("I will now stop :(");
    protect = false;

  }

  if(protect == true && message.content.startsWith("www" || "https")){

console.log('isWebsite true')

  for (var i = 0; i < forbidenWords.length; i++) {
  if (message.content.includes(forbidenWords[i])) {
    break;
   }
}
}



  });
```

any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"www" || "https"` evaluates to `"www"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the additional logic into a helper function.

```
function startsWithWebsiteToken(message) {
  const tokens = ['https', 'www'];
  const length = tokens.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ( message.startsWith(tokens[i]) )
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

if (protect === true && startsWithWebsiteToken(message.content)) {
  console.log('isWebsite true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function for this

```
START_TOKENS = ['https','https','www'];
function doesUrlStartWithToken(url) {
    return START_TOKENS.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        if (accumulator) {
            return true;
        }
        return currentValue.startsWith(url);
    }, false);
}
```

Alternatively, if you only need to [support browser which support `new URL()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-polyfill), it becomes easier to detect certain domains

```
const SPECIAL_DOMAINS = ['youtube.com', 'reddit.com']
function isSpecialDomain(url) {
    const deconstructedUrl = new URL(url)
    const domain = deconstructedUrl.hostname.replace('www.','');
    return SPECIAL_DOMAINS.reduce((e, val) => e || domain === val, false);
}
```